GeoServer Openid access token with keycloak and getting 403 error
I came across this solution (Using openid-connect access token and getting 403 in postman and 401 in logs) regarding setting up OpenID Connect with GeoServer, and I was wondering if you could help us figure out an issue we're facing.
We have Keycloak running on port 8080 and GeoServer on 8081. We've set up authentication using OpenID Connect, and we're passing the access token received from Keycloak as a Bearer token in the headers (access_token) when making requests to GeoServer.
The token itself seems valid, as we verified it using the Check Token Endpoint URL, and it contains the necessary roles. However, when making the request to GeoServer, we keep getting a 403 Forbidden response.
We’ll provide screenshots of our GeoServer configuration and the token being generated.
Do you have any idea what might be causing the 403 error?





